# CScore MediaFoundationEncoder MP3 Encoder Output Stream Empty

Tags: c#, audio, ms-media-foundation, cscore

I'm trying to capture an audio stream in CScore and save it in various encodings and to various locations. One of my intended output encodings is MP3 via the MediaFoundationEncoder APIs.

I am able to successfully encode to MP3 when saving to a local file path. However, if I try to write to a memory stream the memory stream completes writing with a 0 length.

What is wrong with this implementation?

**Working Local Storage**

```
var fileName = "c:\audio.mp3";

using (var encoder = MediaFoundationEncoder.CreateMP3Encoder(waveFormat, fileName, waveFormat.BytesPerSecond))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[waveFormat.BytesPerSecond];
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            encoder.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

**Non-working Memory Stream**

```
using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var encoder = MediaFoundationEncoder.CreateMP3Encoder(waveFormat, outputStream, waveFormat.BytesPerSecond);

    var buffer = new byte[waveFormat.BytesPerSecond];
    int read;
    while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        encoder.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    log.Debug("MP3 File Size: " + outputStream.Length); // <-- Returns as 0
}
```

Comment: Is the `Position` of `inputStream` set to zero? Set a breakpoint @`encoder.Write`. Is it actually being processed?

Comment: Position is set to 0. If I set a log event inside the write loop and log outputStream.Length, it is hit multiple times, but length stays at zero. Suspiciously, if I set a breakpoint inside the loop, it is hit and the ouptutStream is successfully written to.

Comment: Which version are you using? Can't reproduce the issue on my system (win10) with v1.2.1.2

Comment: I am also using v1.2.1.2. It's interesting in that if I add a break point and slow down the processing, the encoder works. Are the MediaFoundationEncoder apis synchronous operations?

Comment: They are. Can you provide a minimalistic sample which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to dispose the encoder after write, this completes the output stream.

```
public static byte[] EncodeBytes(byte[] bytes, WaveFormat waveFormat)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var encoder = MediaFoundationEncoder.CreateMP3Encoder(waveFormat, outputStream, waveFormat.BytesPerSecond);

    var buffer = new byte[waveFormat.BytesPerSecond];
    var inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    int read;
    while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        encoder.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    encoder.Dispose();
    
    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
```